# Add a new button to siebel list applet

Tags: siebel

I have a requirement to add a new button to a List Applet with the caption 'TEST'. I have added a new control to the specific list applet with HTML Type 'MiniButton' and Caption as 'TEST'. The button displayed as follows. what could be the reason for this and how to correct it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the location where you added the button in the list applet? If you add the control to the specific control location like "new","query" they might appear odd. Check also the button's property "HTML Bitmap" - it should be empty.

Comment: I have added the button after QueryAssistant and yes HTML Bitmap is empty. Are there any other causes for this?

Comment: Sometimes the Tools web layout editor produces unexpected results. I would recreate the button by defining it first under Applet > Controls and when all set the drag & drop it in web layout editor. Sometimes if the control is created in Web Layout editor the result is odd.
Is it custom  method you are calling from the button?

Comment: Yes. I have followed the same steps as you have mentioned and it's a custom method I am invoking from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Pirkka mentioned, with post-IP17 Siebel the applet "edit weblayoyut" is only in WebTools and it doesn't work well. If you are using this version of Siebel, you might want to remove check the applet webtemplate item and ensure the SEQUENCE number assigned to it is correct. Just edit it in that list reference. My experience with the latest Siebel versions is that just adding the applet webtemplate item record directly is the best approach.
2. Check the underlying webtemplate that is used for your applet. Make sure that the sequence number assigned at the applet webtemplate item level for your control is actually corresponding to a control section in the underlying list applet webtemplate.
3. Is the applet and/or webtemplate custom? If it is OOTB, can you share the names?